# Can I set the property for a class, which hasn't been specified until run in OC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, weak-linking

I've got a fixed controller with dynamic views as its view. I want to set value for property of a certain view.

Here's code in the controller as below:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Class viewClass;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view =  _viewClass.new;
        if ([_viewClass resolveInstanceMethod:@selector(lineAdded)]) {
            [_viewClass setValue:@YES forKey:@"lineAdded"];
        }
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

In * the certain* view, I've got a property like this.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL lineAdded;
```

It reminds me

> Undeclared selector 'lineAdded'

When I run, it just skip if condition and go on.

**My question is: is it impossible to set property when the class it belongs to isn't specified?**

Hope somebody could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "lineAdded" vs "lindAdded" ... is that a typo in your actual code or only in this question?

Comment: @MartinR I've fixed it. It's just a BOOL property example . And it could be any name you  like. :)

Comment: Of course – as long as you use the same name consistently. Please copy/paste your actual code and error messages to avoid such misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the warning by making the compiler see a declaration of the `lineAdded` selector. Either `#import` a header file that contains a declaration of that property, or declare it another way, for example like this:

```
@protocol DummyProtocol
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) BOOL lineAdded;
@end
```

Second, setting the value of the property doesn't require the `lineAdded` selector. It requires the `setLineAdded:` selector.

Third, the proper way to check whether `self.view` responds to `setLineAdded:` is to ask it, like this:

```
    if ([self.view respondsToSelector:@selector(setLineAdded:)]) {
        [self.view setValue:@YES forKey:@"lineAdded"];
    }
```

Fourth, you were asking `_viewClass` whether its instances respond to `lineAdded`, but then you were asking the `_viewClass` object itself (rather than the `self.view` instance of it) to set its own `lineAdded` property. I fixed that in my code above.

Fifth, you should assign to `self.view` in `loadView`, not in `viewDidLoad`.

If, after all that, it's not setting `lineAdded`, then your view (whatever class you chose) simply doesn't respond to `setLineAdded:`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for pointing out many of my mistakes so patiently and clearly. I followed your suggestions and it works perfectly! Although the warning still exists without adding protocol, it does respond to set value for the key. :)

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. I forgot it yesterday. :P

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting value of `@YES`. You should declare that as `NSNumber` instead of using primitive data type: `BOOL`. When you retrieve, you should use `-(BOOL)boolean` method to retrieve it. As for the `resolveInstanceMethod`, I think you should look into this documentation  to make sure that's the correct logic you are putting in.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html

Comment: [“The default implementation of setValue:forKey: automatically unwraps NSValue objects that represent scalars and structs and assigns them to the property.”](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-178791) You can set a `BOOL` property using `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: Good to know. Let's put it here for reference!